# For loop inside another doesn't work

Tags: bash, for

```
#! /bin/bash
for (( l = 1 ; l <= 50; ++l )) ; do
       for (( k = 1 ; k <= 1000; ++k )) ; do
       sed -n '$l,$lp' $k.dat >> ~/Escritorio/$l.txt
       done
done
```

The script is located in a folder together with 1000 dat files each one having 50 lines of text.

The dat files are called `1.dat`, `2.dat`,...., `1000.dat`

My purpose is to make files `l.txt`, where `l.txt` has the l line of `1.dat`, the l line of `2.dat`, etc. For that, I use the `sed` command to select the l file of each dat file.

But when I run the above script, the txt created have nothing inside...

Where is the mistake?

Comment: I don't think the loop(s) are the problem - did you actually try something simple like `l=2; sed -n '$l,$lp' somefile`? Remember that shell variables are not expanded when inside single quotes. Also `$lp` would refer to a *variable* called `lp` (you probably want `sed -n "${l}p"` instead)

Comment: ive tried one single loop, using for example l=5 and it actually works.

Comment: variables don't expand inside single quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for LINE in {1..50}; do
    for FILE in {1..1000}; do
        sed -n "${LINE}p" "${FILE}.dat" >>"~/Escritorio/${LINE}.dat"
    done
done
```

In your script you are using single quotes for the sed expression, variables don't expand inside single quotes, you need to use double quotes.

Also there is a one liner with awk that can do the same:

```
awk 'FNR<=50 {filename=sprintf("results/%d.dat", FNR); print >> filename; close(filename)}' *.dat
```

Just create the results directory, or change it in the command to another one, `~` does not expand to home there.

Comment: Concur you can't singlequote `sed` command using shell var, but in this case you don't need to quote at all and you only need line number once: `${LINE}p`. OTOH you _do_ need `-n` (as Q had). OT3H agree `awk` is better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for the observations, answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

how about this awk command ? try with small set of dat files

```
awk '{file=FNR".txt"; print $0 > file}' *.dat
```

Comment: note `$0` is not necessary (it is the default for `print`), so `print > file` suffices.